# My Arduino Nicla Voice can't keep a stable connection (keeps on connecting-disconnecting behavior)

Tags: arduino, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy

this is my first question so I'll appreciate every bit of information since this is my final project for school. My partner and I are working on developing a keyword recognition device, this device just includes a Arduino board ([nicla voice](https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/nicla-voice/user-manual#overview)) and a battery so not big deal with that. The problem is with the nicla voice (or at least we think it is); once the sketch is uploaded the board is ready to work and start listening to connections, when we try to connect a phone the Serial port starts logging connected and right away drops the connection, this behavior keeps happening until the phone pairing timeout.

We tried updating the firmware, other sketches, nRF connect but the behavior was the same. This is the code for reference.

```
#include "NDP.h"
#include "Nicla_System.h"
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>

BLEService wordService("180D"); 
BLEUnsignedCharCharacteristic wordRecognitionChar("2A37", BLERead | BLENotify); 

const bool lowestPower = false;

void ledBlueOn(char* label) {
  if (!lowestPower) {
    if (strcmp(label, "NN0:si_sacha") == 0) {
      nicla::leds.begin();
      nicla::leds.setColor(blue);
      delay(200);
      nicla::leds.setColor(off);
      Serial.println(label);

      int wordRecognitionResult = 1;  // Assuming "si_sacha" is recognized
      wordRecognitionChar.writeValue(wordRecognitionResult);
    }
  }
  nicla::leds.end();
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  nicla::begin();
  nicla::disableLDO();
  nicla::leds.begin();

  NDP.onError([]() {});
  NDP.onMatch(ledBlueOn);
  NDP.onEvent([]() {});
  Serial.println("Loading synpackages");
  Serial.println("This is a custom flash for sacha model");
  NDP.begin("mcu_fw_120_v91.synpkg");
  NDP.load("dsp_firmware_v91.synpkg");
  NDP.load("ei_model.synpkg");
  Serial.println("Packages loaded");
  NDP.getInfo();
  Serial.println("Configure mic");
  NDP.turnOnMicrophone();
  NDP.interrupts();

  nicla::leds.end();

  if (lowestPower) {
    NRF_UART0->ENABLE = 0;
  }

  if (!BLE.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Starting BLE failed!");
    while (1)
      ;
  }

  BLE.setLocalName("Sacha");
  wordService.addCharacteristic(wordRecognitionChar);
  BLE.setAdvertisedService(wordService);
  BLE.addService(wordService);

  BLE.advertise();
  Serial.println("- Bluetooth device active, waiting for connections...");
}

void loop() {
  uint8_t command = 0xFF;

  while (Serial.available()) {
    command = Serial.read();
    if (command == 'f') {
      Serial.println("Interrupts disabled");
      NDP.noInterrupts();
    } else if (command == 'o') {
      Serial.println("Interrupts enabled");
      NDP.interrupts();
    }
  }

  BLEDevice central = BLE.central();

  // Check if a central device is connected
  if (central) {
    Serial.print("- Connected to central: ");
    Serial.println(central.address());
    nicla::leds.setColor(green);

    // Wait for the central device to disconnect
    while (central.connected()) {
      delay(200);
    }

    // The central device has disconnected, print the message
    nicla::leds.setColor(off);
    Serial.print("- Disconnected from central: ");
    Serial.println(central.address());
  }

  delay(100);
}
```

The logs on the Serial Port look this way:

```
Loading synpackages
This is a custom flash for sacha model
Packages loaded
dsp firmware version: 19.2.0
package version: Model generated by Edge Impulse
pbi version: 3.2.3-0
num of labels: 4
labels: NN0:no_sacha, NN0:noise, NN0:si_sacha, NN0:unkown
total deployed neural networks: 1
Configure mic
- Bluetooth device active, waiting for connections...
NN0:si_sacha
- Connected to central: 7e:95:54:e7:d5:2b
- Disconnected from central: 7e:95:54:e7:d5:2b
- Connected to central: 7e:95:54:e7:d5:2b
- Disconnected from central: 7e:95:54:e7:d5:2b
- Connected to central: 7e:95:54:e7:d5:2b
- Disconnected from central: 7e:95:54:e7:d5:2b
- Connected to central: 7e:95:54:e7:d5:2b
- Disconnected from central: 7e:95:54:e7:d5:2b
- Connected to central: 7e:95:54:e7:d5:2b
- Disconnected from central: 7e:95:54:e7:d5:2b
- Connected to central: 7e:95:54:e7:d5:2b
- Disconnected from central: 7e:95:54:e7:d5:2b
- Connected to central: 7e:95:54:e7:d5:2b
- Disconnected from central: 7e:95:54:e7:d5:2b
```

That shouldn't happen it should only connect once and keep on sending signals in case the board recognize our keyword.

For the record, we came up with this code so we thought the problem was on our end, but we tried with some code found on the nicla voice [user manual](https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/nicla-voice/user-manual#bluetooth-low-energy) but the behavior was the same. We thought the problem could be related to the app handling the reads from the board on the phone but we also tried using [nFR connect](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/nrf-connect-for-mobile/id1054362403) to scan and establish connection but the behavior was the same. We'll appreciate any lead or solution you can provides us, we are pretty desperate since the deadline is right around the corner.

Comment: Please try uploading a simple example script from the [ArduinoBLE repository](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoBLE/tree/master/examples/Peripheral) just for testing. Maybe the ButtonLED. Would be great to see if a stable connection is possible that way.

Comment: If you are using an Android phone, you can enable [Bluetooth HCI Snoop Log](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/bluetooth/verifying_debugging#debugging-with-logs) to get a much deeper insight into why these disconnects are happening.

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan , thank you for the suggestion. I faced same issue. Here's the code I used from [ArduinoBLE repository](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoBLE/tree/master/examples/Peripheral). I used this code [LED](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoBLE/blob/master/examples/Peripheral/LED/LED.ino). Same logs as above.

Comment: It's kinda weird since on Android devices works just fine but on any Apple device it just keep on getting connected disconnected.